# Upload iOS build online

Tags: iphone

I am uploading ios build on testflight till now. But I am getting the following error on uploading any build (I also tried uploading the previous build again which I already uploaded on it).

> Invalid IPA: Couldn't find executable specified in Info.plist - check the value of your CFBundleExecutable key.

I need to upload the build. Can someone suggest me a site other than testflight where I may upload the ios build or ipa file?

Comment: We had this same issue, it turned out to be the dropped support for armv6 architectures in XCode 4.5. Check that your 'Architectures' setting does NOT include 'armv6'. Bye-bye Iphone 3G!

Comment: I have posted same question with accepted answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523240/error-upload-testflight-invalid-ipa-dsym-not-found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other site you can use is http://diawi.com, i use it on my project now, very helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

We had a problem with CFBundleExecutable  ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}. Our iOS app was for example called OurAppName.

Ran fine in Simulator but when archived and deployed via organizer said CFBundleExecutable was not an executable file.

We checked the plist and the value for CFBundleExecutable was 'ourappname'. we unzipped the ipa > app folder (see how below) and there was a fie called ourappname but it was smaller than expected and not a exe (USE:ls -l should have x at end of -rwxr-xr-x   ).

Bug was caused by a text file called 'ourappname' and when archive was built it took that as the exe and not OurAppName. Answer was to rename and or delete the file with same name as our exe. Do full clean build. and recheck final ipa.

To see contents of OurAppName.ipa :

Rename to OurAppName_ipa.zip (ignore warnings):

DOUBLE CLICK on  OurAppName_ipa.zip to open (creates Payload folder containing OurAppName.app):

rename OurAppName.app to OurAppName_app (ignore warnings will change app bundle to folder).

Open OurAppName_app folder look for ...info.plist for app.

Check CFBundleExecutable is pointing to OurAppName.

Find OurAppName in folder do ls -l make sure it executable (USE:ls -l should have x at end of -rwxr-xr-x).

TIP FOR TEST FLIGHT:

If testflight download fails after 80% with UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD then drag the archive you built to a iOS device using Organizer.

Click on Device > applications and + at the bottom (i think dragging the ipa to the device in the organizer installs it as well).

Comment: For others, to modify the file to be executable, type this in the command line: `chmod 741 YourAppName`

Answer (score 0):

in your info.plist file open as source code form and check CFBundleExecutable key is there or not and make sure it is written as

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
```