# Error Upload TestFlight : Invalid IPA / dSYM not found

Tags: ios, testflight, xcode4.5

This shown on TestFlight web after uploaded.

> "Invalid IPA: Couldn't find executable specified in Info.plist - check
>   the value of your CFBundleExecutable key."

while on Testflight desktop application, shows **dSYM not found**, hence couldn't upload.

this issue suddenly appear after I upgraded **XCode 4.5 with ios6.**

anyone has experienced before, kindly share, and any solutions would be appreciate. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I've solved it. It has to do with your architecture settings. In your target and project build settings **all** of your build settings must be set with **armv 7**.

In Target -> Build Settings:

Architectures = Standard(armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
Valid Architectures = armv7 armv7s

Likewise for your project build settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: must be? but i need to set armv6. maybe that's the reason, but then, previous setting i did set armv6 & armv7, and that was okay.

Comment: Which version of the TestFlight API is this for? There was a bug in some of the v1.1 betas with this that they have since fixed.

Comment: I had mine set for armv6 as well, but it turns out the Xcode 4.5 no longer supports armv6.

Answer (score 11):

I've had this issue too, and I didn't find the answer in the previous responses, so here's mine.

dSYM **may** be included within your executable (and thus in the IPA), but this means you chose to make it so when building your app. In fact, including the dSYM in the executable is only done if the `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` **Build Setting** is set to `NO`.

However, this is heavy content (my app is 5MB, the dSYM is 10MB!), so you generally don't want it to be included with your app when releasing it. So except in development, this flag is better to `YES`. And this is why it the TestFlight Desktop app will show the `dSYM not found` message.

**You can use the TestFligh Co-pilot** (the menubar thing, enabled in TestFlight Desktop app preferences) to detect your XCode last archives. Using this allows TestFlight Desktop to find your XCode archive, and this one always contain the dSYM. Or if you have to use the IPA, you can also upload the dSYM file on TestFlight website (you should see the upload area in the Crashes section for your build).

The dSYM can be found by getting an archive in XCode, right-clicking it and follow `Show in Finder`. Right-click the archive in the Finder, select `Show package contents` (or something like it, I'm on OS X French version), and the package will contain your dSYM file under `dSYMs`.

Answer (score 4):

If you unzip the IPA and look at the info.plist, if CFBundleExecutable doesn't exist or worse the plist doesn't exist we reject the upload.  Uploads are only rejected if they would fail to install, in this case iOS would not be able to locate the executable and your testers would see the generic unable to download message.  If all is well in your IPA and you still get this message, fire off the details and the IPA to support and we'll take a look.

Regarding the desktop app, would you mind sharing a screenshot, we do not reject builds if the dsym cannot be found, we simply skip uploading the dsym.

Comment: yeah, part dsym missing, i could continue uploading, i just thought why it's missing while on the testflight web the .ipa was rejected. my CFBundleExecutable exist on my .ipa. any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: We had this same issue, it turned out to be the dropped support for armv6 architectures in XCode 4.5. Check that your 'Architectures' setting does NOT include 'armv6'. Bye-bye Iphone 3G!

Comment: @HelmiB did you find a solution ? I don't have armv6 in my settings, but I am missing CFBundleExecutable, not had any reply for TF support.

Comment: Any fixes for this? I am using xCode 4.5 and trying to upload via the testflight desktop app / website and get "DSYM Not Found" and it does not allow me to upload the IPA?

Comment: I am certain CFBundleExecutable is set in the Plist, yet I still get the error that CFBundleExecutable is not found.  I even tried moving the Plist to the root, and that didn't help.  Not sure why TestFlight is rejecting the Archive at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. There were an extra space symbol in the end of Product Name (in Project -> Build Settings -> packaging) like

`"My Awesome App "`

Removing this extra space absolutely solved the problem.

Comment: That's most ridiculous but perfect solution! Thanks!