# Error uploading to Testflight Unexpected Error parsing IPA

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, testflight

I am trying to upload my app to test flight. When I use the web interface, I get the error

Unexpected error parsing the IPA, TestFlight support has been notified.

And when I try to upload using the desktop app, it tells me that dSYM is not found, lets me go through the whole process, then give the same error at the end.

[image: Screen in desktop app]

Built in XCode 4.5 for deployment target 5.0.

I have looked at [Error Upload TestFlight : Invalid IPA / dSYM not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523240/error-upload-testflight-invalid-ipa-dsym-not-found) and as far as I can see, all my build settings are set to armv7.

Is there anything obvious that I should check/could be missing?

The only 2 external libraries in the project are test flight sdk and flurry.

Comment: how was this ever resolved? I'd like to know if I'm making the same mistake.

Comment: still waiting to hear back from testflight people. I will update as soon as I have something

Comment: Are you building a distribution build or release build?

Comment: Are you building your app as Ad-Hoc?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having this issue today.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when trying to upload .ipa files. The problem is, that .ipa files don't contain the symbolication information anymore.

Try exporting your app as Xcode Archive instead of building the .ipa for distribution (thats one of the options when you choose 'Distribute...' in the Xcode organizer). This archive contains the necessary dSYM files (if not, you have to check your build settings). If you drop this .xcarchive into the TestFlight desktop client, TestFlight will build the .ipa for you and the upload it.

Make sure to use the same Provisioning Profiles for signing the .ipa in the TestFlight client that you have used when building the archive in Xcode!

Or you can just choose to Show the TestFlight Co-pilot in the menu bar (activate in the settings), the it will automatically detect your Archive.