# Uploading build to Testflight IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, testflight

I have run into this error trying to upload my latest build to Testflight, I cant put my finger on what I might have done differently compared to earlier versions of my app.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
this is the error I get :

```
Invalid IPA: failed to parse the info.plist (exception was: 'ascii' codec can't 
decode byte 0xc3 in position 336: ordinal not in range(128))
```

Comment: I get the exact same thing. Seeing that this question is relatively young, and not much is on the web about it before now I might be tempted to think it's a testflight issue.

Comment: Last night TestFlight was presenting me with errors regarding the TestFlight app_token - and I'm not even using the TestFlight SDK. I hit 'ignore and continue' and it worked fine... just a thought. I push up to multiple builds to TF daily and have never encountered this.

Comment: You were right Nailer. I mailed TestFlight support and after a few hours they had fixed it.

Comment: Yep, e-mailed them too and got the same answer. Now it works fine :) Hooray for good customer support!

Answer (score -2):

[I got it from  this Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523240/error-upload-testflight-invalid-ipa-dsym-not-found)

In architecture settings. select target and project build settings all of your build settings must be set with **armv 7**.

In Target -> Build Settings:

> Architectures = Standard(armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) Valid Architectures = armv7 armv7s

**EDITED :**

[Read This documentation, this may be helpful in your case:](http://plone.org/products/linguaplone/issues/58)

Comment: thanks - unfortunately, as far as I can see, my settings match the above settings

Comment: That question is totally different from this one - the error messages have almost nothing in common except for mentioning the word 'plist'. And if it was the same, you should have voted to close as duplicate instead of copy pasted another answer.